# How disassembler files with Ghidra in cmd

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, decompiling, decompiler, ghidra

How disassembler for example .elf file in Ghidra with cmd. I am trying do this with

```
./analyzeHeadless -import /my/path/file
```

But in arguments required a Ghidra project. I want to disassembler just file without creating project and etc.

I want like this, but not for example in ghidra gui

[image]
[image]

Comment: It doesn't answer the question directly but you could try using Radare2 instead of Ghidra.  It runs in the terminal and is pretty slick and also free.

Comment: Everything assumes a project in Ghidra. To work around this requirement, you could just create a temporary project in /tmp for example.   Look at how wrapper scripts do it, e.g. https://github.com/h0mbre/Headless.